# Upload file with CMIS Service on st:site

Tags: alfresco

I have been uploading files to Company Home pretty easily with this url:

http://myhost.com:8080/alfresco/s/api/path/workspace/SpacesStore/app:company_home/children

Now I am trying to upload to a folder within a site

http://myhost.com:8080/alfresco/s/api/path/workspace/SpacesStore/app:company_home/st:sites/cm:mysite/children

And keep getting this

```
Cannot find object for NodePathReference[storeRef=workspace://SpacesStore,path=app:company_home/st:sites/cm:mysite]
```

Am I missing a special way to declare the path of a site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that there are 6 webscripts related to file manipulation, and it seams each one takes the path in a different way.

I ended up using

http://example.com:8080/alfresco/s/cmis/p/Sites/mySite/Test/children

This particular service it takes Display Names as path segments, and the p itself represents the Company Home segment

I also obtained the same results with this one

http://example.com:8080/alfresco/s/cmis/s/workspace:SpacesStore/i/2aa692bd-0dab-4514-a629-ad36382189f2/children

Which as you can see takes nodeRef Ids as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure how you are uploading to that path but i suppose you need to go into 'documentLibrary' of the site

http://myhost.com:8080/alfresco/s/api/path/workspace/SpacesStore/app:company_home/st:sites/cm:mysite/cm:documentLibrary/children